# Issues with using yum

Tags: redhat, yum

We have a problem with yum on our server (Red Hat 5.7, Apache 2.2.3). If i try for example

```
yum update
```

the following error occurs:

```
    Loaded plugins: downloadonly, replace, rhnplugin, security
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/yum", line 29, in ?
    yummain.user_main(sys.argv[1:], exit_code=True)
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/yummain.py", line 309, in user_main
    errcode = main(args)
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/yummain.py", line 157, in main
    base.getOptionsConfig(args)
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/cli.py", line 187, in getOptionsConfig
    self.conf
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/__init__.py", line 665, in <lambda>
    conf = property(fget=lambda self: self._getConfig(),
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/__init__.py", line 254, in _getConfig
    self.plugins.run('init')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/plugins.py", line 179, in run
    func(conduitcls(self, self.base, conf, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/lib/yum-plugins/rhnplugin.py", line 121, in init_hook
    login_info = up2dateAuth.getLoginInfo()
  File "/usr/share/rhn/up2date_client/up2dateAuth.py", line 219, in getLoginInfo
    login()
  File "/usr/share/rhn/up2date_client/up2dateAuth.py", line 186, in login
    li = server.up2date.login(systemId)
  File "/usr/share/rhn/up2date_client/rhnserver.py", line 50, in __call__
    return rpcServer.doCall(method, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/rhn/up2date_client/rpcServer.py", line 204, in doCall
    ret = method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/xmlrpclib.py", line 1096, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "/usr/share/rhn/up2date_client/rpcServer.py", line 68, in _request1
    raise InvalidRedirectionError(
NameError: global name 'InvalidRedirectionError' is not defined
```

Another problem is that we do not even exactly know what caused this problem. Most probably somebody updated python and changed default version some time ago (this person is not here anymore).

We found some options to repaire yum on the web, but none of them worked. Does anybody have a clue how to fix this?

Comment: Try this command: rhn_check And this if the first didnt come up with anything: rhn-profile-sync let me know if this worked.

Comment: Please check if there was a python update as you asume: ```yum history list all```

Comment: @Tarion, thanks, but it did not work, just as any other yum call. I get the same error

Comment: @IlanHasanov thank you for your tip. rhn_check came up with this error exceptions.NameError.

Comment: @ArthurBlixem Try yum clean all, rm -f /var/lib/rpm/__db*, rpm --rebuilddb,
yum update

Comment: @IlanHasanov yum clean all doesn't work eigher. In fact no one of yum commands works. Whatever you call with yum - you get the same error as above.

Comment: @ArthurBlixem Ok, see my answer. let me know what happens

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if you are behind a firewall, blocking connection to
   mirror.
2. Update libxml2.
3. Try disabling repos in /etc/yum.repos.d — some    of them may
   cause the problem.
4. Try doing `vi /etc/yum/pluginconf.d/fastestmirror.conf`

And change this line

```
enable=1
```

to

```
enable=0
```

If none of those help. Try executing

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64:/usr/local/lib
```

then run

```
yum clean all
```

and test your yum.
If it’s okay — add this export statement to your .bash_profile

Comment: Thanks for your tips. We have actually tried all of them except number 2. It looks like we have to recompile PHP to update libxml2, but we try to avoid recompiling, because it is a production server.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not the python installation like we thought, but that the server could not access RHN. So the problem is resolved now after migrating to a new server. Thanks for everybody's help!